como decodear la api de zeno php?
Buenas tengo esta inquietud , quiero extraer un dato de la api de zeno pero pues no me funciona de esta forma. Su pagina de la api es una pagina que nunca deja de cargar cuando uno entra a un determinado url de una estación:
$FCG = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.zeno.fm/mounts/metadata/subscribe/seezxbu11xhuv'));

$song = $FCG->streamTitle;

echo $song;

Normalmente de esta forma me ha funcionado en la mayoría de veces que eh intentado traer datos de una api determinada . Pero esta vez no me funciona . Como se realiza
Buenas tardes estaba viendo un código que esta en javascript y trate de simplificarlo lo mas que se podía y pues es el siguiente:
<script>

const url = 'https://api.zeno.fm/mounts/metadata/subscribe/seezxbu11xhuv';

// Función para manejar el cableado de eventos
function connectToEventSource(url) {
    // Crea una nueva instancia de EventSource con la URL proporcionada
    const eventSource = new EventSource(url);

    // Agrega un oyente para el evento 'mensaje'
    eventSource.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
       // Llama a la función para manejar los datos recibidos, pasando también la URL
        processData(event.data, url);
    });
}

//Función para manejar los datos recibidos.
function processData(data) {
    // Parse JSON
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    
    //Comprueba si el mensaje es sobre la canción.
    if (parsedData.streamTitle) {
        //Extrae el título de la canción y el artista
        
        const streamTitle = parsedData.streamTitle;
        let artist, song;

            [artist, song] = streamTitle.split(' - ');

            console.log(artist); //muestra en consola
            console.log(song); //muestra en consola
    }
}

//Comenzar a conectarse a la API
connectToEventSource(url);

</script>

Y pues me muestra los datos en la consola, pero lo que deseo hacer es obtener estos datos en dos variables en php así :
$artist y $song y que estas puedan obtener los valores de artist y song de js.
Y pues la verdad de que trate de convertir a solo codigo en php, pero pues la pagina nunca cargaba y hasta ahora solo eh visto que se puede en js de esta forma.
Mi inquietud es saber si los valores de artist y song de js , se pueda declarar en las variables de php . Al final mostrarlas en un echo.

Tal vez anda mal la api?? lo consultaste con ellos?

Hola. ¿Qué muestra un var_dump($FCG);? En este momento, probando la URL que pones en la pregunta, no carga después de un largo rato de espera.

Hasta donde pude probar, la API si retorna información, pero nunca se detiene y continua con el evento de "ping" hasta morir. Esta es la información actual data:{"mount":"seezxbu11xhuv","streamTitle":"BEAST - Bad Girl" Ahora, esta información no ha cambiado desde que comencé a testear. Asi que deberías contacarlos a ellos y consultar por la API directamente.

@gbianchi la api de ellos es asi siempre , también eh visto en js que se puede en consola ver los datos , pero en php hasta ahora no

@A.Cedano en js muestra los datos , pero como una conexión eventos

@Excorpion como se podría ? en php? en js hay una forma , pero pues yo busco obtener los valores en php

Si puedes en js, deberías pasar la info con un ajax quizas, o algo similar ¿?

Si es para consumo de otros clientes no tendría sentido querer acceder a esos datos en PHP cuando los puedes mostrar directamente desde el entorno del cliente. ¿Podrías dar detalles sobre el contexto y lo que quieres hacer realmente? Por ejemplo,  ¿quieres insertar esos datos en una base de datos? ¿quieres crear archivos en el servidor con esos datos?, etc. Si necesitas esos datos en el servidor por algún motivo justificado entonces los puedes pasar allí vía Ajax o Fetch.
